# Switch excluding/including VAT prices on productpage

Tags: price

I want to change price view of my products on my Magento 2 sites.
In the standard config, I only have these three options:
1) show including VAT
2) show excluding vAT
3) show including & excluding VAT

We want to show the price excluding & including VAT.
So leading price is the excluding VAT price.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way (not the best) would be a little CSS to switch the font sizes. Not ideal, but could help before you find a better solution:

```
.price-including-tax > span {
    font-size: 0.7em !important;
}
.price-excluding-tax > span {
    font-size: 1.8em !important;
}
```